# how do i enable multi-user access to node application stored online?

Tags: mysql, express, session

i have a node application that collects a set of inputs from the user and then uses those inputs to query a back end database. the application also allows the user to enter information that will be pushed to the back-end database. the issue that im having is that the initial set of inputs are stored within the application code and change when multiple users are accessing the application at the same time. ex- if user x enters values to review project x and user y enters values to view project y at the same time. if user x refreshes the view, the application will refresh to show project y.

my question - is there a way for each user to open the application within a unique session so that the parameters and inputs are specific to that user and are unaffected by any other users?

i have looked into localStorage and sessionStorage but im running into issues altering a lot of code and i have a feeling that there is a better way.

Comment: WHat language is used to process the data from the page into the database?

Comment: @RiggsFolly express

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to sessions and local storage. Using both will allow you to give each user unique data corresponding to their input.

That way when a user refreshes the page rendered would have access to their inputs and not another user's because their input data is being stored on local storage.

Don't forget to make sure your frontend is using local storage to show the information you want to be cached for each user.

I would personally use Passport.js or express-sessions

The additions to the code shouldn't be too bad. I believe the Net Ninja has a good tutorial on how to use Passport.js